# fast heap dumps but on out of memory

Tags: java, memory-leaks

We all know good old flag `+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` for taking heap dumps when JVM runs out of memory. Problem with this is that for large heaps this takes more and more time.

There is a way to take fast heap dumps using GNU Debugger...
You effectively take the core file of the process (very fast) then convert it to heapdump format using `jmap`... this is the slowest part of the work.

However this is only if you take it manually, when your java apps run in containers there is usually a fixed timeout until your app will be killed non gracefully... for kube i believe it is 30 seconds by default.

For many reasons i do not want to extend this timeout to larger number. Is there a way to trigger only core file dump when out of java runs out of memory? or we are just limited with whatever `+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` flag offers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 possible solutions but it wont be only for out of memory situations but crashes too:

1. You can use java's `-XX:OnError` option to run your own script or gcore, (gdb) generate-core-file(depends to your OS) to create an core dump that you can later use a debugger(like gdb) to attach to it.
2. You can enable auto core dumps in your OS in the way it provides. **For Redhat**:

To enable: Edit the related line in file /etc/systemd/system.conf as `DefaultLimitCORE=infinity`

Reboot and remove the limits of core dump by `ulimit -c unlimited`.

When your application crashes, the dumb must be created in its working directory.